# Environment variable equivalent to conserve String

Tags: java, shell, variables, testing

I want to know if it's possible to create a variable like an envornement variable but that is capable to conserve a string ?

I want to do this because i'm doing java test and i have plenty of website to test, and i'm always doing the same tests

My architecture is very special, but to resume, i want to create a shell script that will specify the website URL and be stored in this variable and then run the java test get this variable and run.

Any ideas ?

Comment: what's wrong with `.properties`?

Comment: Do you want to keep value between start/stop jvm?

Comment: I don't know how to do it with .properties ..

Comment: The test are going to be executed one by one so no, i just want this variable to be erased and written again with an over URL

Comment: lots of tutorials written on `.properties`. THere's a great web google.com that can help you finding them.

Comment: Never add more information in comments; instead rework your question. And it is really not clear what exactly you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can read and write variables to a [file](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)
2. You can use `nosql` key-value data storage(like [Redis](http://redis.io/)) if you have plenty of variables to read/write